# First number $\ge n$ that is divisible by $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a good way to compute the first value $\ge n$ that is divisible by $k$?

Right now I am computing $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor k$ but it doesn't always work.

Comment: shouldn't $\left\lceil \frac{n}{k}\right\rceil k$ do it?

Comment: @RolfHoyer Looks like it does. It would be nice to not have to deal with floats, though, or is that not possible here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $(n-(n\mod k))\mod k$? This should do the job.

Comment: $n=100$, $k=2$, result should be $100$, not $102$

Comment: @user62753 how about now?

Comment: still not correct

Comment: @user62753 OK. I checked it this time, it works, provided $n \mod k$ is not 0.

Comment: Better version might be n + (k - (n%k))%k

Comment: @user62753 Yeah. let me edit my answer with that then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $n \equiv 0\pmod k$, then then $n$ works, as $k$ divides $n - 0 = n$.

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod k$, that means $k$ divides $n - 1$, so $n - 1  +k$ works.

If $n \equiv 2 \pmod k$, that means $k$ divides $n - 2$, so $n - 2 + k$ works.

Do you think you could generalize this, assuming you have the ability to find the residue of $n$, modulo $k$?

Comment: Problem is when $n \equiv 0$ mod $k$

Comment: Well, if you're willing to accept two cases, I would think $n \equiv 0 \pmod k$ would be the nicest case possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$u(n, k)
=k\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil
$
being the smallest multiple of $k$
that is $\ge n$.

We now use
$\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil
=\lfloor \frac{n+k-1}{k} \rfloor
$.
To see this,
write $n = ak+b$
where
$0 \le b \le k-1$.
Then
$\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil
=a
$
if $b=0$
and
$a+1$ if $b > 0$.
But
$\lfloor \frac{n+k-1}{k} \rfloor
=\lfloor \frac{ak+b+k-1}{k} \rfloor
=a+\lfloor \frac{b+k-1}{k} \rfloor
=a$
if $b=0$
and $a+1$
if $b > 0$

Therefore
$u(n, k)
=k \lfloor \frac{n+k-1}{k} \rfloor
$.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim** $m=\left\lfloor\frac{n+k-1}{k}\right\rfloor k$ works.

**Proof** This is obviously a multiple of $k$. To prove that it is the smallest larger than $n$ we must show 
$$m-k < n \leq m$$

To see this, we use 
$$\frac{n+k-1}{k}-1 < \left\lfloor\frac{n+k-1}{k}\right\rfloor \leq \frac{n+k-1}{k}$$

Thus
$$\frac{n-1}{k} < \left\lfloor\frac{n+k-1}{k}\right\rfloor \leq \frac{n+k-1}{k}\\
n-1< k \left\lfloor\frac{n+k-1}{k}\right\rfloor \leq n+k-1 \\
n-1< m \leq n+k-1 \\
$$

Now, since $n,m $ are integers we get the implications
$$n-1< m \Rightarrow n \leq m$$
and
$$ m \leq n+k-1 \Rightarrow m-k \leq n-1 <n$$

Therefore 
$$m-k < n \leq m$$
as claimed.